# Nuget restore fails with FileFormatException

Tags: mono, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have Jenkins CI running commands that build my docker containers.

One of the steps for building my containers requires that I run the following NuGet restore..

`RUN mono /usr/bin/NuGet.exe restore /src/MyApp.sln -NoCache -Verbosity detailed`

About 50% of the time, the build works, and the other 50% of the time, it seems to hang or timeout and gives me the following output to the console.

`[91mSystem.IO.FileFormatException: The specified archive is invalid.
  at System.IO.Packaging.Package.OpenCore (System.IO.Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean ownsStream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean ownsStream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, FileMode packageMode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage.EnsureManifest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NuGet.OptimizedZipPackage..ctor (IFileSystem fileSystem, System.String packagePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.OpenPackage [0m[91m(System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 [0m[91m`

This is running inside a VM, so there is the possibility of inconsistant network availability I suppose.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem (mainly spotty DNS and packet drops) and ended up scripting around it by checking the nuget exit code and retrying the restore. Would love to see a real solution